# Return an array of the SUM of two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I was recently asked this in my 1st coding interview and it has still got me stumped...

The task is:

- Return an array that is equal to the sum of two arrays
- Arrays may be blank
- Arrays may be different sizes
- Items in array will always be type(int)
- You cannot use a library or numpy or any built in functions

Example input with expected output:

```
add_two_array([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) => [5, 7, 9]

add_two_array([9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4]) ==> [1, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: I can't understand the output of second example. Why it returns the array with 4 elements?

Comment: `987+654 = 1641`

Comment: Those are not arrays. Those are lists. Did they ask you to add **arrays** at the interview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand the requirement 'cannot use any built in functions'. What's the point in using the language. This only uses the list type to append and reverse (slice):

```
def add_two_array(arr1, arr2):
    def arr_to_int(arr):
        n = e = 0
        for d in arr[::-1]:
            n += d*10**e
            e += 1  # would be easier to use enumerate
        return n    # return sum(d*10**e for e, d in enumerate(arr[::-1])

    total = arr_to_int(arr1) + arr_to_int(arr2)
    result = []
    while total:
        result.append(total%10)
        total //= 10
    return result[::-1]

In []:
add_two_array([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

Out[]:
[5, 7, 9]

In []:
add_two_array([9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4])

Out[]:
[1, 6, 4, 1]
```

An alternative (slightly uglier) way would be to use a reverse index and carry a remainder. Uses the ternary operator to set a default value of 0:

```
def add_two_array(arr1, arr2):
    result = []
    rem = 0
    for i in range(max(len(arr1), len(arr2))-1, -1, -1):
        n = (arr1[i] if i < len(arr1) else 0) + (arr2[i] if i < len(arr2) else 0) + rem
        result.append(n%10)
        rem = n//10
    if rem:
        result.append(rem)
    return result[::-1]

In []:
add_two_array([9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4])

Out[]:
[1, 6, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem statement is missing the indication that you actually want to add digits and carry over the extra ten:

```
def add_two_array(A,B,carry=0):
    if not (A or B or carry): return []
    carry += A[-1] if A else 0
    carry += B[-1] if B else 0
    return add_two_array(A[:-1],B[:-1],carry//10)+[carry%10]


r = add_two_array([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
print(r) # [5, 7, 9]
r = add_two_array([9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4]);
print(r) # [1, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Isn't `sum()` a built in :) Adding lists using a slice hack to avoid `IndexError` - nice!

Comment: `sum()` is indeed a built-in. I use it so much I didn't realize it.

Comment: See my comment, I think it is dumb to state "no builtins".

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool problem and can be solved recursively without using any built-in functions and methods whatsoever. Here, `_add2` and `_add3` are the recursive helper functions and `add` is the wrapper.

```
def _add2(a, carry):
    if a == []: return [carry] if carry else []
    s = a[-1] + carry
    digit = s % 10
    carry = s // 10
    return _add2(a[:-1], carry) + [digit]

def _add3(a, b, carry):
    if a == []: return _add2(b, carry)
    if b == []: return _add2(a, carry)
    s = a[-1] + b[-1] + carry
    digit = s % 10
    carry = s // 10
    return _add3(a[:-1], b[:-1], carry) + [digit]

def add(a, b):
    return _add3(a, b, 0)

add([9, 8, 7], [1, 6, 5, 4])
#[2, 6, 4, 1]
add([1, 6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7])
#[2, 6, 4, 1]
```